# How do I cancel out double quote in Sikuli w/ Python?

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I am using Sikuli to create an automation script and am currently struggling with the 'type' function as the input I am attempting to type has quote marks.

Example:

```
type('h', Key.CTRL)

wait(1)

type('<tbody class="MenuTableBody">')
```

The actual outcome when it types this is:

```
<tbody class=@MenuTableBody@>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Workaround maybe worth trying is first define the string.

```
stringSample = str('<tbody class="MenuTTableBody">')

type(stringSample)
```